# Why select invalid field in subquery could run in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

For the following sql

```sql
CREATE or replace TABLE
  temp.t1 ( a STRING)
;
insert into temp.t1 values ('val_a');

CREATE or replace TABLE
  temp.t2 (b STRING)
;
insert into temp.t2 values ('val_b');

create or replace table `temp.a1` as
select distinct b
from temp.t2
;

select  distinct a
from `temp.t1`
where a in (select distinct a from `temp.a1`)
;
```

Since there is no `a` in `temp.a1` and there should be an error here, However, the output of Bigquery is

```
Row   a 
1     val_a
```

Why the result happened?

On the other side, when run `select distinct a from temp.a1;` there is one error `Unrecognized name: a` comes up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is:

```
select distinct a
from `temp.t1`
where a in (select distinct a from `temp.a1`);
```

You *think* this should be:

```
select distinct t1.a
from `temp.t1` t1
where t1.a in (select distinct a1.a from `temp.a1` a1);
```

And hence generate an error.  However, the rules of SQL interpret this as:

```
select distinct t1.a
from `temp.t1` t1
where t1.a in (select distinct t1.a from `temp.a1` a1);
```

Because the scoping rules say that if `a` is not found in the subquery then look for it in the outer query.

That is the *definition* of SQL.

The solution?  **Always qualify column references.** *Qualify* means to include the table alias in the reference.

Also note that `select distinct` is meaningless in the subquery for an `in`, because `in` does not create duplicates.  You should get rid of the `distinct` in the subquery.